# Filtering JSON only if contains all items in search array match

Tags: arrays, json, filter, match

I could have sworn I've seen examples of this in multiple places, but can anyone tell me how I only return items from the JSON object below that match ALL of the tags in a search array - eg:

```
[
    {
        "ref": "1",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Description 1...",
        "tags": ["A2", "B1", "D1", "E3", "E4"]
    },
    {
        "ref": "2",
        "brand": "Title 2",
        "description": "Description 2...",
        "tags": ["A1", "A2", "C1", "D1", "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4"]
    },
    {
        "ref": "3",
        "title": "Title 3",
        "description": "Description 3...",
        "tags": ["A5", "A6", "B1", "D1", "E3"]
    },
    {
        "ref": "4",
        "title": "Title 4",
        "description": "Description 4...",
        "tags": ["A5", "A6", "B1", "E1", "E3"]
    }
]
```

And my search array to match/find within the tags array would be:

```
["B1", "D1"]
```

This would return the filtered JSON with only item ref 1 and 2 in this instance...

Comment: what language are you using and what have you attempted so far?

Comment: @NickParsons - I'm using Javascript - the solution below seems to have got the result I was after. All solutions I'd tried were only looking for a single match vs matching ALL items in the search array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using java script then this should work..

```js
const array1 = [
    {
        "ref": "1",
        "title": "Title 1",
        "description": "Description 1...",
        "tags": ["A2", "B1", "D1", "E3", "E4"]
    },
    {
        "ref": "2",
        "brand": "Title 2",
        "description": "Description 2...",
        "tags": ["A1", "A2", "C1", "D1", "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4"]
    },
    {
        "ref": "3",
        "title": "Title 3",
        "description": "Description 3...",
        "tags": ["A5", "A6", "B1", "D1", "E3"]
    },
    {
        "ref": "4",
        "title": "Title 4",
        "description": "Description 4...",
        "tags": ["A5", "A6", "B1", "E1", "E3"]
    }
]


let tags = [ "B1", "D1"]

console.log(array1.filter( f => tags.every(e => f.tags.includes(e)))
);
```